# Prevent nested <Link/> component from inheriting path from previous <Link/> (React router 4)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router-v4

I have a Dasboard component where I have React-router
`<Link/>` components that are linking to

```
http:<procjethos>/team
```

Inside `<Team/>` component I have a `<Link/>` components that should link to

```
http:<projecthost>/list/:listId
```

But instead, it inherits from previous link and I get

```
http<projecthost>/team/list/:listId
```

// Dashboard.jsx

```
  render() {
    const { shoppingLists, teams } = this.props;

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Toolbar isHomePage/>
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="dashboard">
            <h2 className="dashboard__heading">
              <TeamIcon />
              Cohorts
            </h2>
            <ul className="dashboard__list">
              {_map(teams, team => (
                <li className="dashboard__list-item" key={team._id}>
                  <Link to={`team/${team._id}`}>
                    <CardItem name={team.name} />
                  </Link>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
```

// Team.jsx

```
    <Fragment>
        <Toolbar />
        <div>
          Cohort of id:
          {id}
          <ul>
            {_map(lists, list => (
              <li className="dashboard__list-item" key={list._id}>
                <Link to={`list/${list._id}`} replace>
                  <CardItem name={list.name} />
                </Link>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
```

How to achieve the desired behavior in React-Router 4 with nested LINKs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `/` before link path

```
 <Link to={`/list/${list._id}`} replace>
       <CardItem name={list.name} />
 </Link>
```

Comment: LOL, Thank you, my friend,...such funny syntax mistake! 
Probably I need to refresh for a while